# reload kendo after search mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Heello,
Kendo grid cannot reload results  after search .I'm posting results with code below. After that nothing is happend.What is wrong here.Thanks

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "invoice-form" }))
 {
```

to controller and script which is calling on btnSearch

```
<script>

                $(function() {

                    $("a.saveInvoicePopup").on('click', function (e) {

                        debugger;
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var dataObj = serializeByFieldsWrap(".invoiceForm");
                        var dataUrl = $(this).data('url');

                        // dataObj.ToolboxId = toolboxId;


                        $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');

                        var result = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: dataUrl,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: dataObj


                        });

                        result.done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);


                            if (data.Success) {
                                var grid = $('#invoices-grid').data("kendoGrid");
                                grid.dataSource.data(result);
                                grid.refresh();

                            }

                        });

                        result.fail(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                    });

                });


            </script>
```

Comment: Someone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the line below, **replace** `result` with the actual variable that holds the received data:

```
grid.dataSource.data(result);
```

In your code, `result` is the [jqXHR object, not the actual response](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Also, **remove** `refresh()`, as it is not needed:

```
grid.refresh();
```

Comment: @dimondi You mean here grid.dataSource.data(result); instead result to add ->dataObj  ?

Comment: @dimondi this is not help me